# RelativeSource never called

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, relativesource

I want to bind a command which is in the code behind to user control button(`ICommand`) which is in `UserControl.Resources`

So I wrote a code using RelativeSource. But It didn't work.

I tried to solve this using converter for debugging.

But even this wasn't called.

Here is the code I made. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Thank you.

> XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.Common.SubMenuPanel"
             xmlns:controls="...."                
             ....
             mc:Ignorable="d">

<UserControl.Resources>            
    <controls:SubMenuButton x:Key="TerminateSystem" 
                            ButtonName="Terminate System" 
      [[DOESN'T WORK]] -->  Execute="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=TerminateSystemCommand
                                    , Converter={StaticResource DebugDummyConverter}}"
                            ImageURI="...png"/>       

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="LoginViewSubMenuItems">
        <CollectionViewSource.Source>
            <system:ArrayList>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="TerminateSystem"/>
            </system:ArrayList>
        </CollectionViewSource.Source>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource LoginViewSubMenuItems}}"/>
</Grid>
```

> Code Behind

```
public partial class SubMenuPanel : UserControl
{
     public ICommand TerminateSystemCommand => new RelayCommand(() => Do Something);

     public SubMenuPanel()
     {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for having a ListBox with only a single item, i.e. the SubMenuButton? Putting a UI element in an array into the ItemsSource is not a correct approach.

Comment: Actually There are many 'SubMenuButton' in 'LoginViewSubMenu Items'. I cut it for making you concenrate on main issue.

Comment: Is `SubMenuButton` a `UserControl` or an extension to `Button`?

Comment: it's an extension to 'Button'

Comment: There may be an issue with the Execute property. Please also show its declaration, and perhaps tell us why you have it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the `ICommand` to an `Execute` property. The property you should be binding to is `Command`, i.e.

```cs
<controls:SubMenuButton x:Key="TerminateSystem" 
                        ButtonName="Terminate System" 
                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType= 
                                 {x:Type UserControl}}, Path=TerminateSystemCommand
                                    , Converter={StaticResource DebugDummyConverter}}"
                       ImageURI="...png"/>
```

Assuming the other properties in the button are not causing other issues, that should resolve it.

EDIT:

I am including the code I have verified to work. Since I don't have your definition for `SubMenuButton`, I just used a `Button` instead:

XAML:

```cs
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Button x:Key="TerminateSystem" 
            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=TerminateSystemCommand}">
        Say Hello World!!!!
    </Button>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="LoginViewSubMenuItems">
        <CollectionViewSource.Source>
            <system:ArrayList>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="TerminateSystem"/>
            </system:ArrayList>
        </CollectionViewSource.Source>
    </CollectionViewSource>            
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource LoginViewSubMenuItems}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```cs
public ICommand TerminateSystemCommand =>
        new RelayCommand(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World!!!"));
```

Comment: In case there were no such property, the XAML would not compile. Assume the Execute property exists.

Comment: I made ''Execute'' dependency property to bind ''Command'' property in the button.

Comment: @Clemens, yes, what I meant is for a button to react to a click, it should bind to the `Command` property. This is why I mentioned that "assuming the other properties in the button are not causing other issues". I'll update my answer to include the code I created to get this (or very similar) scenario working.